# Can we integrate swagger with ear (with multiple war file) in JBOSS?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

We are deploying our app as an EAR and this EAR contains multiple WAR files with different context paths.

We have added the swagger as module in jboss and used it as dependency in the EAR.

Does swagger support docs in EAR? Is there any doc or link to guide to integrate with EAR?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Include annotations just like you would if it was a war - the annotations are java, aren't they?

Since your context-root depends on war name (or you would have defined it separately), it will work just fine.

As far as swagger-ui is concerned, you can include it as a separate war in itself with a dynamic url -

```
url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "api/swagger.json";
```

Comment: when i add swagger-core.jar as part of my each war's lib it is working. But when I add swagger-core as separate module in JBOSS and added that module as dependency in my all war it is not generating the swagger.json.    **Is it JBOSS module issue or Swagger issue?**

Comment: This is a jboss  modules issue. Add the jar on EAR level with jboss-deployment-structure.xml file

Comment: Thanks Sampada. Its working when adding in war lib (anyway need to add in each lib of war). Not working when adding in EAR level with jboss-deployment-structure

Comment: Glad the answer helped. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people facing a similar issue. For more information, take a look at our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks and welcome to [SO]!